# Basic calculation with root roots and power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Sorry for the boring question but I just need someone to remind me the way to calculate this:

$\displaystyle \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + x^2 = a^2$ (i used carrot sign cause i dont know how to do factorial in my mac keyboard)

The answer is $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}a$ but i forgot how to calculate this type of exercise, can someone be kind enough and help?

tnx

Comment: I rewrote your question using $\LaTeX$, please check thatI didn't alter the meaning of the question.

Comment: @GitGud thanks buddy, but the answer is x = to √3 divided by 2...is that the same?

Comment: @GitGud  
it's (a/2)² + x ² = a ² (i don't really know all the shortcuts to write it properly so i used the parenthesis)

Comment: @GitGud yes, just the answer is (√3/2)..

Comment: I hope everything is OK now, please check.

Comment: @GitGud great! thanks! where can i find all this shortcuts to write it properly next time?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is an introductory tutorial. You can also click on [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/355926/edit) to see how the text is formatted. Another thing you can do is right-click the math you want to know how to type and click on TeX commands under the show math tab.$\LaTeX$ is better learned by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see: $\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)=\dfrac{a^2}{2^2}=\dfrac{a^2}{4}$, if you replace this in your original equation you get:
$$
\dfrac{a^2}{4}+x^2=a^2
$$
If you multiply by $4$ both sides of this equation you obtain the following:
$a^2+4x^2=4a^2$, and if you subtract $a^2$ from both sides you get $4x^2=3a^2$, and finally after you divide by $4$ both sides of the equation you obtain:
$$
x^2=\dfrac{3a^2}{4}
$$
Last step is to take the square root of both sides and don't forget that squaring a quantity always produces a non-negative number independently of the sign of original quantity, so we will get two answers that will only differ by the sign.
$$
x=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a
$$

Comment: it's (a/2)² + x ² = a ² (i don't really know all the shortcuts to write it properly so i used the parenthesis)

Comment: @Heberto del Rio Nice work. I'll upvote if you delete the first line which has nothing to do with the question as it is after all the edits.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac a2\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{2^2}=\frac{a^2}4.$$ Thus, using the difference of squares identity $$y^2-z^2=(y-z)(y+z),$$ the following are equivalent: $$\left(\frac a2\right)^2+x^2=a^2\\x^2+\frac{a^2}4-a^2=0\\x^2-\frac{3a^2}4=0\\x^2-\left(\frac{a\sqrt{3}}2\right)^2=0\\\left(x-\frac{a\sqrt{3}}2\right)\left(x+\frac{a\sqrt{3}}2\right)=0.$$ Now what can you conclude from that? (Incidentally, the answer you mention is incorrect.)

Comment: thanks allot, your answer did help. (can't up vote since im too new :/)

Comment: You're very welcome! (Apologies for not responding sooner.)